# Como faço para juntar o background de uma div com o do rodapé?

Tags: html, css, div

Eu gostaria de retirar esse espaço em branco entre o footer e a div do input. Já tentei criar um "span" para os dois para deixar só um "background-color", mas não deu certo.

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```css
div#newsletter{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
div#newsletter input{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px #606060 solid;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: -50px 5px 30px 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }
div#newsletter input.botao{
    width: 20%;
}
    
footer#rodape{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000000;
footer#rodape a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="newsletter">
            <form>
                <h1>Quer receber nossas promoções?</h1>
                <input type="text" name="nome" value="" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Digite seu email">
                <input type="button" value="Receber" class="botao">
            </form>
        </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="rodape">
            <p>Copyright &copy; G&R Imports <br/>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a> | <a target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com">Instagram</a></p>
        </footer>
```

Comment: Coloque o *HTML* e o *CSS* que estão gerando esse resultado na forma de um [mcve]

Comment: Existe uma margem, entre esses dois elementos, remover essa margem pode solucionar o problema. Ou encapsule os dois elementos dentro de uma div pai e defina o background-color nela. Esse é o máximo que dá pra ajudar sem um exemplo do seu code.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: dnd, se puder marca minha resposta como certa.

Comment: @LukasTakahashi não é assim que funciona a página. Você tem orientar o usuário recém chegado de como funciona o processo de aceitação, pois ele pode não saber como funciona. Você pode indicar esse link [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/137387)

Comment: @Dragonox essa pergunta possui uma resposta ao problema proposto. Caso essa resposta tenha lhe ajudado considere a aceitá-la como correta. Caso não saiba como aceitar uma resposta leia: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/137387).

Comment: @AugustoVasques Obrigado pela orientação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns elementos do html tem margins e paddings já predefinido. Tente colocar o código abaixo no topo do seu documento de estilos, esse code vai remover a margin e padding predefinidos de todos os elementos.

```
   *, *::before, *::after{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="newsletter">
        <form>
            <h1>Quer receber nossas promoções?</h1>
            <input type="text" name="nome" value="" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Digite seu email">
            <input type="button" value="Receber" class="botao">
        </form>
    </div>
    </section>
    <footer id="rodape">
        <p>Copyright &copy; G&R Imports <br />
            <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a> | <a target="_blank"
                href="http://instagram.com">Instagram</a></p>
    </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *::before, *::after{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div#newsletter {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #000000;
        }

        div#newsletter input {
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 2px #606060 solid;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 30%;
            margin: -50px 5px 30px 5px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        div#newsletter input.botao {
            width: 20%;
        }

        footer#rodape {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            background: #000000;
        }

        footer#rodape a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
```